# Showing Dynamics CRM 2015 out of box views on HTML pages hosted outside the CRM

Tags: iframe, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create a portal where we can access the records in crm. This portal will be hosted outside the CRM as a web application and not as a web resource in crm.

In one of the pages i like to show the out of the box  crm view. So i used a html page with an iframe in it .i specified the source of the iframe to crm view  below is my iframe code

Now when i open this html page directly via my web application the iframe i am getting the below error

"This content can’t be shown in a frame

There is supposed to be some content here, but the publisher doesn’t allow it to be displayed in a frame. This is to help protect the security of any information you might enter into this site.

Try this

Open this in a new window

"

But if i create a web resource in crm with the same html page i can see the view with no issues.

If i paste the below url directly in the browser i can also see the view

http://xrmdroid:5555/XRMfinsights/main.aspx?etn=opportunity&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003001}&viewtype=1039&navbar=off&cmdbar=false

But i am unable to use this in an iframe in a html page in an application .Is it possible to use url addressable form and views in application hosted outside crm ?

Thanks in advance

ravi sagi

Comment: I think we cannot use any CRM components(views, lookupWindows, web resources etc.) outside the CRM environment.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't *think* this will work.

Looks like Microsoft have setup their content to not display in an iframe for starters. I suppose there is a chance you may be able to find a way to work around this.

I cant find anything official on this for your exact situation, but these MSDN quotes seem somewhat relevant:

[Open forms, views, dialogs and reports with a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx)

> Outside the application, where pages do not have access to the
>   Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm function, use window.open or a link to open
>   a specific record or form for an entity. The entire application will
>   open for any of the Updated entities.
>
> Displaying an entity form within an IFrame embedded in another entity
>   form is not supported.

Its also worth bearing in mind that if you do get this to work the users will require CRM logins - which could be an issue depending on the sort of portal you are trying to build.